# How to convert a user input (string variable) to an Excel table reference

Tags: excel, vba

I have a complex Excel 2016 stocks and options trading application, but a simple question with a not quite obvious answer. After market close, the trader is prompted for the name of the spreadsheet containing the day's transactions that are stored in an Excel table, one row for each trade.

**Question**: How do I convert the user input, e.g. a string variable "Mar06", to the Excel table name listed in the Name Manager as tblMar06, that the application can use to perform statistics using structured table references, without multiple array or list object or VLOOKUP(..., INDIRECT) statements?

Simple example:

[image]

```
'User is prompted for spreadsheet name, e.g. Mar06, then  
tableName = "tbl" & "Mar06"  
'tableName is then converted to an Excel table name (the question is how?)  
...  
...  
...  
'The Excel table name is then used for statistic calculations, e.g.  
If ([tblMar06[@Type]] = "Opt") AND ([tblMar06[@Action]] = "SLD") Then     
    [tblMar06[@[Realized P&L]]] = [tblMar06[@Qty]] * 100 * [tblMar06[@Price]] - _ 
    [tblMar06[@Comm]] - [tblMar05[Cost]].Rows(i)  
Else
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I devised a simple solution to the above problem that let me continue to use structured Excel table references with a generic table name, e.g. tblTrades, that remains the same for all worksheets

```
...  
Dim ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject, sWS As String, sTbl As String, _ 
    tblSave As ListObject
...          
'User inputs the current spreadsheet name, e.g. Mar06  
...  
sWS = "Mar06"    
sTbl = "tbl" & sWS 'current trades table name, e.g. tblMar06  
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sWS)  
ws.Activate  
set tbl =wsListObjects(sTbl)  
Set tblSave = tbl    
tbl.Name = "tblTrades" 'rename table
...      
If ([tblTrades[@Type]] = "Opt") And ([tblTrades[@Action]] = "SLD") Then  
    [tblTrades[@[Realized P&L]]] = [tblTrades[@Qty]] * 100 * _
    [tblTrades[@Price]] - [tblTrades[@Comm]] - Cost  
    'where Cost comes from a previous day's buy  
Else  
    ...  
End If  
tblSave.Name = sTbl 'restore table name to tblMar06  
...
```

Answer (score 1):

- With **NO** error testing for invalid entries of the worksheet name
- And with **NO** error testing for invalid table entry on that worksheet

```
Option Explicit
Function myTbl(wsName As String) As ListObject
    Set myTbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName).ListObjects("tbl" & wsName)
End Function

Sub tester()
    Dim LO As ListObject
Set LO = myTbl(Application.InputBox("Sheet Name: ", , , , , , , 2))

Stop

'Do your calculations

End Sub
```

If the worksheet name or table name is invalid, you will get a `subscript out of range` error in the Function that sets LO to the desired table.

With regard to your formula and Excel type structured references, you will run into some problems.

An Excel formula cannot write to another cell. So even using the `Evaluate` method, you will still need to capture the results of your `IF` statement, and then write it out to the desired location in your worksheet.

Doable, but, in my opinion, more complex than just doing it with native VBA functions.

In addition, if speed becomes a problem, you could easily adapt the native VBA method to read/write to/from vba arrays rather than to/from the worksheet with a significant speed increase.

Readability might be an issue, but here is an example of your formula re-written to use native VBA functions, but still retaining the useful names of your table:

***Note that the `Cost` factor in the formula below will return a zero, as it is not clear to me where you are obtaining the Cost to be applied for the first and last items in your example***

```
Sub terfuge()
    Dim LO As ListObject
    Dim I As Long

Set LO = myTbl(InputBox("Worksheet Name: "))
With LO.ListColumns
    For I = 1 To LO.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
       If .Item("Type").DataBodyRange(I) = "Opt" And _
          .Item("Action").DataBodyRange(I) = "SLD" Then

            .Item("Realized P&L").DataBodyRange(I) = _
                .Item("Qty").DataBodyRange(I) * 100 * _
                .Item("Price").DataBodyRange(I) - _
                .Item("Comm").DataBodyRange(I) - _
                .Item("Cost").DataBodyRange(I)
        End If
    Next I
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209343/discussion-on-answer-by-ron-rosenfeld-how-to-convert-a-user-input-string-variab).